# Proving complex series is convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, geometric-series

**Question 1: Test the following series for convergence**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2+i}{3-4i}\right)^{2n}$$

I got that it was convergent by doing a ratio test and getting 
$$p = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} < 1 $$
which checks out for convergence. Wondering if that was the correct way to approach solving this series.

**Question 2:    Same as Question 1**
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1+i}{2-i}\right)^{n}$$

I am unsure how to approach solving this question and any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Application of the root test is trivial.

Comment: Your method is perfect, and really the only way to check the convergence of a geometric series. As long as $|r|<1$, $\sum r^n$ will be convergent. In the second case, again, the ratio is $\sqrt2/\sqrt5$, less than $1$, giving convergence.

Comment: @Lubin Are you saying that the ratio test is the only way to really check for convergence for a geometric series? 

I was told to multiply my first series by $$\frac{3+4i}{3+4i}$$ Why would I want to do that?

Comment: Indeed I am saying that. Since $|2+i|=\sqrt5$ and $|3=4i|=5$,  the quotient of the absolute values is $1/\sqrt5<1$. You could have used the trick suggested to you just as well, by multiplying top and bottom of $((1+i)/(2-i))^n$ by $(2+i)^n$, but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Apologies: I said your answer was perfect, but that $\sqrt3$ is off, and I’m wondering how you got it.

Answer (score 1):

The first series is a geometric series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^n$ with $q = \left( \frac{2 + i}{3 - 4i} \right)^2$. Since

$$ \left| \frac{2 + i}{3 - 4i} \right| = \left| \frac{2 + i}{3 - 4i} \frac{3 + 4i}{3 + 4i}\right| = \left| \frac{2 + 11i}{25} \right| = \frac{\sqrt{4 + 121}}{25} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $$

we have $|q| = \frac{1}{5} < 1$ and so the series converges.

Similarly, for the second series we have $q = \frac{1 + i}{2 - i}$ and

$$ |q| = \left| \frac{1 + i}{2 - i} \right| = \left| \frac{1 + i}{2 - i} \frac{2+i}{2+i} \right| = \left| \frac{1 + 3i}{5}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 9}}{5} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} $$

and agan, the series converges.

Comment: Why didn't you square 25 and then take the square root of it? Also for 5. You seem to leave the denominator  completely alone when it comes to calculating the magnitude.

Comment: Also thank you so much for giving me such a detailed answer.

Comment: Never mind, I realized how dumb that question was.